# How do I add a downloaded texture to an object in 'simple' mode

Tags: materials

Firstly I just want to add a downloaded texture image to an object in Blender 2.92 to ALL surfaces, I do not want to apply a different texture/materials to each face.  I have watched a video tutorial which uses version 2.80 which I can follow using 2.80 but in 2.92 I have come to a 'wall'. I select my object, open the material panel, select NEW, click on the small o next to Base Color to select an image instead of a color which in 2.82 opens a window to select a texture type. This does not happen in 2.92 and I can't work out what to do. Help.

Comment: Is it because by default 2.92 has a simple material automatically assigned to the object? If you go to Material Properties, and click on the dot next to Base Color, you can select 'Image Texture', and select your image.

Comment: In 2.82 the dot was right to the color field, now it's on the left. The dot on the right is for setting animation keyframes.

Comment: Thanks to you both. It's always a problem watching video tutorials which use an older version. I didn't know that by default 2.92 has a simple material automatically assigned. Right now my head is swimming with trying to learn all the 'tools', what they are useful for and also hot keys. It's complex for a beginner. Thankfully I now know heaps more than I knew last week when I first started using Blender.

Comment: That begs another question. If in the future I find a tutorial using 2.82 and 2.92 is different and I can't work out how to get around it, is it ok to make the change to my (2.92) object using 2.82 and continue later with 2.92. This might save me posting a question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to provide a quick gif, if anything changed in 2.92.

1. Click Base Color > Image Texture
2. Select <kbd>Open</kbd> (it will open a new window)
3. Navigate to your texture

(to have textures visible on your model, you need to be in Material preview)

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Jachym. I followed your video and still cannot get the texture image to go onto my object. Firstly do I assume correct that you always use 2.92 for these video tutorials? Secondly this is what I do -

Comment: Hi :). The process is the same since Blender 2.8 (but probably since 2.6). Keep in mind textures don't show up in solid mode - you need to be in material preview :)

Comment: OK now I see it I think. I have to select Texture Paint from the top of screen which divides the screen into two, on the left side shows the 'unwrap' and on the right my object? I tried to add an image of my (Blender) screen and thought someone said that I only needed to drag the image file onto this panel  but that didn't work.     Once again I had googled "Blender material preview" which did NOT disclose anything. It was just a matter of try this and that until I found Texture Paint top of screen which I selected and once again frustration crept in.

Comment: Hi :). Not really - just follow my gif, I didn't open any other editor. It might benefit you to watch some beginner tutorials. Related: [Blender Manual - Material Preview](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#material-preview).

Comment: I did watch your gi maybe 30 times - I am NOT kidding. I even captured it as a video and then watched it in slow motion to ensure I didn't miss something. I did EXACTLY as I saw in the gif. The only thing I am having trouble with is how to get to Material Preview and so assume that is all that is preventing success for me.

Comment: Oh, right :). It's those four circle icons in top right. They switch viewport shading, one of them is material preview :).

Comment: At last I see the light. There also is a preview selection in the materials panel which had me rattled. I have learned something. Do I assume correctly that when I select an image for the material it is wrapped around my object? I have watched so many tutorials including many put out by Blender and the ones for adding a material all seem to be about adding roughness, occlusion, displacement etc and unwrapping the object to apply them to each face. My project does not require any of this just the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124209/discussion-between-jachym-michal-and-john-arnold).